# python program sign in not working

Tags: python

```
list_names = ("A"+"B"+"C")
username = input("enter your username: ")
if username == (list_names):
    password = input("enter your password "+username+": ")
elif username !=(list_names):
    print("that is not a valid username")
if password == ("password"):
    print("allowing access...")
    time.sleep(3)
elif password != ("Password"):
    print("password was incorrect "+username)
```

I tried to make a program for a project i am doing and i have came across a problem. i have tried for a long period of time to why this doesnt work but i can simply not understand why it is printing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\PYTHON\My Work.py", line 10, in <module>
    if password == ("password"):
NameError: name 'password' is not defined
```

Comment: NameError: name variable is not defined has been asked many times on this forum, consider searching what the error means prior to posting here. glad you now know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `password` inside of an `if`-block, so if the `if`-block does not execute, `password` will remain undefined. Also, your syntax for the `list_names` is incorrect. Update

```
list_names = ("A"+"B"+"C")
```

to

```
list_names = ['A','B','C']
```

The former executes to

```
list_names = ("ABC")
```